# Custom DropDown Semantic-Ui-React

Tags: semantic-ui-react

The problem is how to customize DropDown semantic-ui-react component

I tried to import s`emantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css` to `index.js`. Everything was OK, except all other styles fall down. And I want not default DropDown, but customized one.

```
'const Options = [{
  value: 'Программирование', text: 'Программирование', key: 'Программирование',
}, {
  value: 'Дизайн', text: 'Дизайн', key: 'Дизайн',
}];

<Form.Select
            fluid
            options={Options}
            placeholder='Категория'
            required={true}
          />'
```